# Jenkins perforce triggered build on windows?

Tags: jenkins, triggers, perforce, build-automation

I feel totally in the dark, and hope you guys can help.

So I have a jenkins server setup connect to p4v and everything running smoothly.
I can trigger the builds on jenkins manually without any problems.

Now however I'd like to setup so Jenkins (using the perforce plugin) acually polls from perforce everytime I submit something new in a specific folder.

This seems fairly straightforward running on linux, just adding a script file in perforce and a perforce trigger to run that file using curl to send a message to jenkins to start the build.

However i'm running windows, and I dont find any information about how to solve this particular problem on windows. Anyone, to help?

The main problem seems to be that all tutorials I find on this uses a .sh script which isnt run in windows, I wonder if there is some other way to do this in windows?

Comment: Many people have their Jenkins job poll Perforce, rather than having a Perforce trigger that talks to Jenkins. You might try that approach, it might be easier for you.

Comment: I put it to poll now as a temporary solution, but would still love to know how to make a trigger work in this circumstance, at least for the knowledge of it :)

Comment: Have you checked out this HowTo? https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/219152268-Use-POST-Commit-Hook-with-Perforce-Triggers

I haven't tried this myself. I run a script every couple of minutes to see if there is anything submitted that warrant a new build (some paths aren't worthy...). Then I have it build changelist-by-changelist so I know for certain which one broke the build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I managed to solve this by using the following Jenkins plugin:**
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Build+Token+Trigger+Plugin

**and curl:**
https://curl.haxx.se/

If someone else has the same issue here is the step by step process I went through to set it up on Windows.

1. In your Jenkins project, enable: Trigger builds remotely (e.g., from scripts)
2. Enter an Authentication Token, can be anything, ex: `buildCode`
3. On the command line as p4 admin enter: `p4 triggers`
4. In the trigger, file go to the bottom
5. Enter the actual p4 trigger: `SomeTriggerName change-commit //DepotLocationToTriggerOn/... %//DepotLocationOfScriptToBeTriggered/trigger.bat%`

**Observe:** When the batch file to be run in the trigger is in a depot path it must be surrounded by %

6. Submit the trigger.bat to p4 in the choosen location. The batch file need to contain the following code `C:\curl-7.60.0-win64-mingw\bin\curl.exe -u userID:APIToken JenkinsIP/job/TestJob/build?token=buildCode`

**Curl must be in that specific folder on the p4v server machine.**

**The userID and APIToken is found by going to the user drop down and enter Configure, then clicking API Token.**

Hope this might help someone else with a similar problem :).